# Pusher/Laravel Echo stops working on Ionic 3.9.2 intermittently

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, mobile, pusher

Normally it works.

When I create an appointment on the Laravel webapp, the Ionic mobile app's listview updates in real-time with the new appointment (thru Laravel Echo and Pusher).

```
...
@Injectable()
export class UpdateService {
  private echoStarted: boolean;
  private channel: string = null;
  private dataChanged = new Subject<void>();
  public dataChanged$ = this.dataChanged.asObservable();

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {
    window.Pusher = require("pusher-js");
    if (this.auth.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.startEcho();
    }
    this.auth.authenticated$.subscribe(status => {
      if (status) {
          if (!this.echoStarted) {
            this.startEcho();
          }
        } else {
          this.stopEcho();
        }
    });
  }
...
```

But at some point the real-time listener just stops completely and continues to not work until I hard-refresh the mobile page or reset the mobile app. In other words, when I create a new appointment, the mobile app listview just sits there with no automatic update.

This problem seems to be reproduced when switching to another mobile app then coming back, or when putting the mobile app in background mode (pressing phone power button then coming back in). Happens on both Android and iOS.

This problem does not occur with the real-time updates on the webapp's front-end Pusher implementation.

So I'm suspecting this is a mobile app code issue, and hopefully not a fundamental stability problem with Ionic and Pusher.

Maybe something to do with the OnResume trigger where the real-time listener/process is getting doubled up and failing? Or maybe the listener/process fails as it was receiving some new data but going into background mode? The intermittent failure is what makes this issue thorny to think about.

Wondering if you've experienced a similar issue. Any illumination is greatly appreciated.